# How to select only the last row among the subset of rows satisfying a condition in R programming

Tags: r

The dataframe looks like this :

```
Customer_id A B C D E F G
10000001    1 1 2 3 1 3 1
10000001    1 2 3 1 2 1 3
10000002    2 2 2 3 1 3 1
10000002    2 2 1 4 2 3 1 
10000003    1 5 2 4 7 2 4
10000003    1 5 2 6 3 7 2
10000003    1 1 2 2 1 2 1
10000004    1 2 3 1 2 3 1
10000004    1 3 2 3 1 3 2 
10000004    1 3 2 1 3 2 1 
10000004    1 4 1 4 1 3 1
10000006    1 2 3 4 5 1 2 
10000006    1 3 1 4 1 2 1 
10000008    2 3 2 3 2 1 2
10000008    2 3 1 1 2 1 2
10000008    1 3 1 1 2 2 1
```

There are multiple entries for each customer_id. I need to create another data frame from this existing data frame. The new data frame should contain only the last row for every customer_id. It should look like this

```
10000001    1 1 2 3 1 3 1
10000002    2 2 1 4 2 3 1 
10000003    1 1 2 2 1 2 1 
10000004    1 4 1 4 1 3 1
10000006    1 3 1 4 1 2 1 
10000008    1 3 1 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (hard to code without the data in R format):

```
dataframe[ rev(!duplicated(rev(dataframe$Customer_id))),]
```

or better

```
dataframe[ !duplicated(dataframe$Customer_id,fromLast=TRUE),]
```

Comment: A possibly absurd alternative: `dat[cumsum(rle(dat$Customer_id)$lengths),]`

Comment: Not too absurd. Absent `duplicated` function it would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I am sorry I couldnot login these days, your reply did help. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(. ~ Customer_id, data = DF, FUN =  tail, 1)
##   Customer_id A B C D E F G
## 1    10000001 1 2 3 1 2 1 3
## 2    10000002 2 2 1 4 2 3 1
## 3    10000003 1 1 2 2 1 2 1
## 4    10000004 1 4 1 4 1 3 1
## 5    10000006 1 3 1 4 1 2 1
## 6    10000008 1 3 1 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I was trying to understand this code and I have a question, does the '1' in the above mentioned code mean the 1st row from the last ?? In that case would "aggregate(. ~ Customer_id, data = DF, FUN =  tail, 2)" fetch the last but one row for each customer id ??

Comment: The argument `1` is for `tail` function. It means it will give 1 row from the end. if you use 2, then you will get 2 rows from the end.

Comment: Oh okey I understand it now, Thankyou for the replies :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume your data is named `dat`,

Here's one way using `by` and `rbind`, although the other two methods (`aggregate` and `duplicated`) are much nicer:

```
> do.call(rbind, by(dat,dat$Customer_id,FUN=tail,1))
##    Customer_id A B C D E F G
## 2     10000001 1 2 3 1 2 1 3
## 4     10000002 2 2 1 4 2 3 1
## 7     10000003 1 1 2 2 1 2 1
## 11    10000004 1 4 1 4 1 3 1
## 13    10000006 1 3 1 4 1 2 1
## 16    10000008 1 3 1 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :). So we would be fetching each last row of the customer_id and then bind all the rows to form a data frame right ?